# Exception: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException While using Spring post Method

Tags: java, spring, post, request

I have the following code to map post API in my controller. I have defined a model for POST request parameters.

```
public class CreateUserBody {
    String CandidateId = "";
    String EmployeeId = "";
    String CompanyId = "";

    public String getCandidateId() {
        return CandidateId;
    }
    public String getEmployeeId() {
        return EmployeeId;
    }
    public String getCompanyId() {
        return CompanyId;
    }
}
```

When I trigger this API Im getting HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException. Please help  me with this issue.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/SetEmployeeIdOneByOne/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody void SetEmployeeIdOneByOne(@RequestBody CreateUserBody createUserBody) throws Exception{
        String CandidateId = createUserBody.getCandidateId();
        String EmployeeId = createUserBody.getEmployeeId();
        String CompanyId = createUserBody.getCompanyId();
        SetEmployeeID.SetEmployeeIDOneByOneInteger(CandidateId, EmployeeId, CompanyId);
    }
```

I'm calling the API like...

[image]

Comment: how you sending a data to your API ?

Comment: @SudhirOjha this please see the screenshot

Comment: Your path in your Postman call doesn't match your code. Did you forget a `/`?

Comment: @SudhirOjha Now?

Comment: Please show how you annotated your controller class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting data in `form-data` post your data in `raw` and then select content type as `application/json`. And in body your data should be like following:

```
{
  "CandidateId":"3",
  "EmployeeId":"5696969",
  "CompanyId":"15272"
}
```

and your requested url in postman should be like following:

```
http://localhost:9199/SetEmployeeIdOneByOne/
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Sudhir answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52014996/5289288), please try to annotate your controller like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ats-api")
class MyController {
    @PostMapping("/set-employee-id-one-by-one")
    public void(@RequestBody CreateUserBody createUserBody) {
        ...
    }
```

And it is uncommon to use `CamelCase` in paths, please consider to use `kebab-case` instead